# PackageReference condition is ignored

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, csproj, docfx

In my VS 2017 project I reference docfx.console package and I want it to be used only when certain condition is met. But the package gets used for all builds.

Here is a part of my project. I want docfx.console to be used when configuration is Installer/AnyCPU and VS is building net40 flavor.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net40;netstandard1.3;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <!-- ... -->
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;Installer</Configurations>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)'=='net40' ">
    <!-- ... -->
    <PackageReference Include="docfx.console" Version="2.30.0" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Installer|AnyCPU'" />
  </ItemGroup>

    <!-- ... -->
</Project>
```

Is there a way to use docfx.console in Installer build for net40 only?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional reference in Visual Studio Community 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46796065/conditional-reference-in-visual-studio-community-2017)

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT No, it is not a duplicate. At least the `Choose/When` approach don't help.

Comment: known and documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#adding-a-packagereference-condition): "at presently, only the TargetFramework variable is supported"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Even i was looking for referencing nuget packages on condition based (load only when expected constant is set in DefineConstants). Though @Luke Schoen Solution worked for me, I could make it work without the external targets file.

Solution is to include your PackageReference using **Choose > When**

Make sure to have this block after your PropertyGroup which has DefineConstants.

```xml
<Choose>
    <When Condition="$(DefineConstants.Contains('My_CONST'))">
        <ItemGroup>
            <PackageReference Include="MyPackage">
                <Version>1.0.6</Version>
            </PackageReference>
        </ItemGroup>
    </When>
</Choose>
```

Answer (score 15):

To summarize, even with the condition "false", the package will be imported.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">    
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.0;netcoreapp2.2;net472</TargetFrameworks>
    <Platforms>x64;x86</Platforms>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="false">
      <PackageReference Include="MyPackage" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

We found that we can work around this issue by putting the packagereference in a different file, and making the import of the file conditional.

Separate file: packagerefs.targets

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">    
  <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="MyPackage" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">    
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.0;netcoreapp2.2;net472</TargetFrameworks>
    <Platforms>x64;x86</Platforms>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="packagerefs.targets" Condition="false" />
</Project>
```

Comment: Wow great way to fix it! I've created a GitHub issue in msdocs page where it clearly says this should be working as I wasn't sure where to create it! https://github.com/NuGet/learn.microsoft.com-nuget/issues/1840, upvote it or any future linked issues if anyone sees this!

Comment: Also worth noting, the `<Import Project=".." />` has to be at the root level, it cannot be nested inside a `<PropertyGroup />`

Comment: After a nights of sleep, and creating a new solution + project to try and reproduce this, the condition seems to be working this morning! Not sure what happened yesterday, but this definitely fixed at the time! I also tried reproducing on original project but ItemGroup Condition seems to be getting respected. Anyhow this did somehow manage to get me around my original issue!

Answer (score 3):

> PackageReference condition is ignored

This is an [known issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4837) about the new style csproj PackageReference to work with content/Tools files in a nuget package.

In the package `docfx.console`,  it looks like `docfx.console` has "`content`", "`build`" and "`tools`" without .NET code in it, just random files:

[image]

In this case, when we install this nuget package, nuget does not do anything. So it seems gets used for all builds. That because:

> NuGet packages that work with Packages.config, don't always work in
>   transitive NuGet environments (projects using Project.json or
>   PackageReferences). Packages that work in transitive NuGet
>   environments must use "contentFiles" instead of "content" -- you can
>   have both, if a package would like to work in both environments. Also,
>   install.ps1/uninstall.ps1 doesn't execute in transitive NuGet
>   environments -- however, init.ps1 will work in both Packages.config
>   and transitive environments.

At this moment, there is not a perfect solution, so [the issue 4837](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4837) is still open.

To resolve this issue, the NuGet `docfx.console` package needs to be changed to use [contentFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files) and define targets and would typically reference a tool by using `$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\tools\MyTool.exe`. If you put this `PackageName.targets` file into the a build directory, it will be automatically included into the project referencing the NuGet package.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I ended up using console docfx tool instead of the NuGet package.

Comment: I have asked a DocFX question here if you are interested to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50018471/namespaces-not-wrapping-properly-with-ie11.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had also same kind of problem - but root cause was that some of msbuild properties were not defined when nuget package building was performed - in particular `$(SolutionName)` was not defined. `Condition` still gets evaluated, only it's returning true for some reason. (You can test this by putting `Condition="false"` - it will be omitted).

Solution for me was to check if property is defined, for example like this:

```
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(SolutionName)' != '' and $(SolutionName.Contains('SolutionCustomTag'))">
    <Reference Include="...">
```

Te first statement `'$(SolutionName)' != '' and`  - tests that property is defined.