# NuGetCommand doesn't restore conditional packages

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have a C# project that defines two packages with conditions:

```
// MyProj.csproj

  <Target Name="OpenCV Version" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile">
    <Message Text="Using NenPack V5" Importance="high" Condition="$(UseVersion5)"/>
    <Message Text="Using NenPack V4" Importance="high" Condition="!$(UseVersion5)"/>
  </Target>

  </ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NenPack" Version="5.1.7" Condition="$(UseVersion5)" />
    <PackageReference Include="NenPack" Version="4.9.2" Condition="!$(UseVersion5)" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The build flag `UseVersion5` determines if to load the v5 version of `NenPack` (private NuGet)

In Azure Dev Ops we have configured a CI pipeline:

```
// azure-pipeline.yml

    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      displayName: 'Restore Packages for Packing'
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
        feedsToUse: 'config'
        nugetConfigPath: 'nuget.config'
        externalFeedCredentials: 'PrivateFeedCred'
        buildProperties: 'UseVersion5=true'
        noCache: true

    - task: MSBuild@1
      displayName: 'NuGet Packing'
      inputs:
        solution: '**/*.csproj'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
        msbuildArguments: '/noAutoResponse /restore:false /t:Pack /p:UseVersion5=true /p:PackageOutputPath=$(nugetOutput)'
        maximumCpuCount: true
```

Although the `UseVersion5` is set to `true` and the log output says `Using NenPack V5` (so the condition is working), it still use v4 in the packed output nuspec file:

```
// MyProj.nuspec

<dependency id="NenPack" version="4.9.2" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
```

Why is it ignoring the `PackageReference` condition and take the V4 version instead of `V5` although we are asking for 5 and get the right log message?

Any way to enforce the `NuGetCommand` to download the `V5` package?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56028935/4919526) help you?

Comment: @mu88 thanks, but I saw this, and it didn't solve my problem. I have the opposite issue. It ignores the condition when I set the flag to `true`.